# Get percentage of total when using GROUP BY in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I have a SQL query that I'm using to return the number of training sessions recorded by a client on each day of the week (during the last year).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total_sessions
     , DAYNAME(log_date) day_name
  FROM programmes_results
 WHERE log_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
   AND log_date <= CURDATE() 
   AND client_id = 7171
 GROUP 
    BY day_name
 ORDER 
    BY FIELD(day_name, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')
```

I would like to then plot a table showing these values as a percentage of the total, as opposed to as a 'count' for each day. However I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to do that without another query (which I'd like to avoid).

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can add the number of trainings per day in your client application to get the total count. This way you definitely avoid having a 2nd query to get the total.
2. Use the [with rollup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier in the query to get the total returned in the last row:

   `...GROUP BY day_name WITH ROLLUP ORDER BY ...`
3. Use a subquery to return the overall count within each row

   `SELECT ..., t.total_count
    ...FROM programmes_results INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as total_count FROM programmes_results WHERE <same where criteria>) as t --NO join condition
    ...`

This will have the largest performance impact on the database, however, it enables you to have the total number in each row.

Comment: Thnaks for the tip RE rollup, that proved useful in pointing me in the right direction here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived table

```
select day_name, total_sessions, total_sessions / sum(total_sessions) * 100 percentage
from (
query from your question goes here
) temp
group by day_name, total_sessions
```